# Break Batch Script Execution during Pause

Tags: batch-file, pause

I'm developing a complex, long-running batch script, and came upon a little issue when debugging.  I have a command-line window open to the root path of the script, so I can type `myscript.bat` to fire it off for testing.  I am using `PAUSE` commands between statements to watch the behavior of the script.  However, I discovered that typing CTRL+C during a `PAUSE` command to cancel execution is simply interpreted as a key to continue execution, rather than breaking the script as intended.

I know I can simply kill/close the command window, but it's a little annoying to navigate back to the correct path in a new command-window every time.  Is there a way to properly break a batch script's execution easily while it is currently in a `PAUSE`?

---

**Edit:** It looks like `PAUSE` works fine in simple scripts, as indicated by @dbenham.  However, if you have multiple `PAUSE` statements nested inside of a `FOR` iteration, then you can't break in the middle of the `FOR` iteration - only at the end.  Here is a sample script that demonstrates the issue:

```
@echo off

for /l %%y in (2008, 1, 2013) do (
    echo 1
    pause
    echo 2
    pause
    echo 3
    pause
    echo 4
    pause
    echo 5
    pause
)
```

If you try to terminate any of the first four `PAUSE` statements, you will find that your terminate command is ignored and execution continues anyway.  But once you reach the end, to the fifth `PAUSE`, you do get the terminate prompt (in the example output below, I was pressing CTRL+C at every prompt):

```
Z:\>test
1
Press any key to continue . . .
2
Press any key to continue . . .
3
Press any key to continue . . .
4
Press any key to continue . . .
5
Press any key to continue . . .
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```

Any ideas how to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works fine for me on Win 7 (32 bit)

Here is a trivial test script

```
@echo off
echo Before
pause
echo After
```

When I run the above without pressing `<Ctrl-C>`, I get the following:

```
D:\test>test
Before
Press any key to continue . . .
After

D:\test>
```

When I press `<Ctrl-C>` at the "Press any key" prompt, I get:

```
D:\test>test
Before
Press any key to continue . . .
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y

D:\test>
```

**EDIT: Solution to follow-up question**

It doesn't need to be in a loop. The problem exists with any parenthesized block of code. The entire block is parsed in one pass and then executed from memory.

```
(
  echo Before 1
  pause
  echo Before 2
  pause
  echo After
)
```

I don't think there is a fix using the PAUSE command. But I have a simple solution that should give the debug functionality you want. Just make sure that the PAUSE environment variable is not already defined before you run your script.

```
@echo off

:: ------------------------------------------------------
:: Include this block of code at the top of your script
::
setlocal
if not defined pause (
  set "pause=choice /m "........................Continue "&if errorlevel 2 exit"
  cmd /c ^""%~f0" %* ^"
  exit /b
)
:: ------------------------------------------------------


:: Now use %pause% instead of pause anywhere you want within your script
:: Press Y to continue, N to quit
:: The script will immediately terminate if you press N, even if in the
:: middle of a CALL

:: Here is a simple demonstration

call :sub1
exit /b

:sub1
call :sub2
exit /b

:sub2
for /l %%N in (1 1 3) do (
  echo ----- %%N ------
  echo Before 1
  %pause%
  echo Before 2
  %pause%
  echo After
)
exit /b
```

Comment: Hmm, I do too.  There must be something unique about my script.  Let me see if I can make a script that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @mellamokb - Are you redirecting input at any point?

Comment: Nope.  But I am using a lot of nested `if`/`for` clauses, something like `for /l %%y in (2012, 1, 2013) do ( ... pause ... )`

Comment: I think I figured it out.  If there are multiple `pause` statements inside of a single `for` iteration, then you can't actually break the script until the end of that iteration.  Weird.  Try this script for example, and you can't break the first for `pause` statements: http://pastebin.com/BEtSKBer

Comment: @mellamokb - I appended a solution that should work within blocks of code. It was an interesting problem to solve.

Comment: That is an awesome idea!  Thanks for taking the time to look at it.  This should work great.

Answer (score 2):

One way to overcome the problem of `PAUSE` in parenthesized blocks is to call a subroutine:

```
@echo off
goto run

:pause
echo %*
pause >nul
exit /b

:run
(
  echo Before 1
  call :pause Please consider aborting with Ctrl+C
  echo Before 2
  call :pause Really consider aborting with Ctrl+C
  echo After
)
```

This solves the problem at least in Windows 10, and allows custom messages for `PAUSE`.